# jquery refresh plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, timer, live

Hi i have this script http://jsbin.com/ajaneh ,  when i make an action throw ajax

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: domain+"/home/register_working_time/",
             dataType: 'json',
             data: data,
             success: function(dt){
                $("#work_time").timer({time:dt.timerTime, stopTimer : dt.stopTimer});
             }

});
```

plugin is not refreshing  ,  i need to add `stopTimer : false` from php , but no reaction from timer , i think i have to refresh plugin , but how ? thank you !!!!

**Update**

Thank you for helping , i funded my mistake , value for `stopTimer : false` , was not boolean  , and i added to check `if (settings.stopTimer !== 'true')` , and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean something like `clearTimeout(timer);`

```
if (!settings.stopTimer) {
    timer = setInterval(do_time, 1000);
} else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer , but i dont need `clearTimeout(timer);` because `timer = setInterval(do_time, 1000);` is not running